# How do I remove identical words from two separate text files using HashMaps in Java?

Tags: java, file, text, hashmap, comparison

I am working on taking out connecting words (conjunctions) from a book file in Java, so only words of substance remain. I am able to read the information of the book.txt file, split it into tokens, remove punctuation, and sort by how many times the words are said. However, I am not able to figure out how to compare this book data with another file of these conjunctions mentioned earlier. I've thought of putting each connecting word into a HashMap, but the number values and words together just don't seem right to me. Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do this efficiently? I am still a beginner programmer :)

Thank you!

Comment: Could you give an example of the kind of conjunction you are looking for?

Comment: yep sure thing. in my conjunctions file, i have these words:
and
that
but
or
as
if
when
than
because
while
where
after
so
though
since
until
whether
before
although
nor
like
once
unless
now
except

Comment: I see. So do you simply want to remove all instances of those words, or are there more criteria?

Comment: A `(Hash)Map<String, Integer>` would be for a frequency table. A `(Hash)Set<String>` for a collection of words. An internet search will give you the 100 most recently used words. A frequency map can use `map.merge("java".toLowerCase(), 1, Integer::sum);` You probably need two passes to remove frequent words.

Comment: @EwanBrown Yep, I just want to remove all instances of where those conjunction words from conjunction.txt are in the book.txt file

Comment: @I_Respect_Women Great! The code I supplied in my answer should do that

Comment: @EwanBrown thank you :) ill give it a try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you have a body of text stored in a file from which you'd like to remove 'Conjuction' words. The conjunction words are stored in a separate file.

If what you want is to remove all instances of those Conjunction words from your text, the following code will do that. (assuming you have already loaded in the text and conjunctions into two strings)

```
//Load text from file into string 'text'
//Load conjuctions from file into string 'conjs'

//Split the conjunctions into separate elements of an array
List<String> conjsArray = Arrays.asList(conjs.split("\\s+")); 

//Iterate over each conjunction word, and remove all instances of it from the text
for (String conjunction : conjsArray){
    text = text.replaceAll(conjunction, "");
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I think this would work. Thank you for the help!!

Comment: @I_Respect_Women Glad I could help :)

Comment: Great, this solves the purpose. Just a few inputs
1. `Arrays.asList(conjs.split(" ")` already returns a list, so you need not add this in another list
2. `conjs.split(" ")` should be better written as `conjs.split("\\s+")`, include all whitespaces between words and not just one single space between words
3. `text.replaceAll("( "+conjunction+" )", " ");`. `You could just do text.replaceAll(conjunction, "");`. No `" "` will add a space in place of the words, which will mean there will be 2 spaces between words once the conjunction is removed, so use "" - replace by nothing, just erases it.